# TypeScript error when property is set on `this` of the Component : Property 'X' does not exist on type Classname

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I don't want to include this property in state or props. Just on `this` of the component.

This is what I am doing:

```
class accountTrack<{},{}> {
  constructor() {
    this.resetConfig();
  }

  async init(userMoId:string, accountMoId:string, email:string) {
    this._id = uniqueId();
    this.userMoId = userMoId;
    this.accountMoId = accountMoId;
  }}
```

But for some reason, I am getting this kind of errors:

[image]

Looking for the way of proper usage

Answer (score 0):

Just declare it the component:

```
class accountTrack<{},{}> {
 declare _id?:  string;
 declare userMoId?:  string;
 declare accountMoId?:  string;

  constructor() {
    this.resetConfig();
  }

  async init(userMoId:string, accountMoId:string, email:string) {
    this._id = uniqueId();
    this.userMoId = userMoId;
    this.accountMoId = accountMoId;
  }}
```

Comment: You don't need the declare keyword when defining properties on a class :)

Comment: @badatcpp what is an alternative way?